# Laravel Tinker on php 7.2.19

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, tinker

Tinker in laravel closes itself everytime when I try to get a result of a command harder than 1+1.

Laravel: 5.5.38

php: 7.2.19

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdjyV.png)

Comment: What if you do the commands on two separate lines?

Comment: No, that isn't solution, because code right in terms of php, and it's allows writing

Comment: Also don't work another commands like php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
```

Or

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
```

Comment: any command is crashed a tinker, just gets out of shell

Comment: If any problem in my code it shows error. May be it's your shell problem too

Comment: that's a major problem, tinker doesn't throws any errors, just closes

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will get the same exeption, check your connection to databases in env file better, because i spent 3 hours for resolving my own mistake.